# Compiler warning regarding a template

Tags: c++, templates, bit-manipulation

```
 1  #include <cstdlib>
 2  #include <iostream>
 3
 4  enum { SIZE_PER_CHUNK = ((1<<16) / sizeof(unsigned)) };
 5 
 6  class TrueType {} ;
 7  class FalseType {} ;
 8
 9  template< std::size_t V, bool B = (((V) & ((V) - 1)) == 0) > class IsPowerOfTwo_;
10  template< std::size_t V >   class IsPowerOfTwo_< V, true  > : public TrueType {};
11  template< std::size_t V >   class IsPowerOfTwo_< V, false > : public FalseType {};
12  
13  typedef IsPowerOfTwo_< SIZE_PER_CHUNK >   IsPowerOfTwo;  
14
15
16  int main() {
17     IsPowerOfTwo p2;
18     
19     std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
20     return 0;
21  }
```

The following code gives a compiler warning (gcc 4.6.2, /project/dfttools/compile/lnx-x86/gcc-4.6.2):

> warning: suggest parentheses around '-' in operand of '&' [-Wparentheses]

The warning points to line 13, but it is probably related to the expression in line 9.

Any solution?

Comment: gcc sometimes  points to the line where a temlpate was instantiated instead of where the definition is. just put the parentheses there, its mostly not a good idea to rely on operator precedence rules.

Comment: There are parentheses galore!

Comment: Please don't add line numbers to the code you post - it makes copy and paste to try your code in my compiler unnecessarily hard. (You can use comments within the code to indicate specific lines that are relevant still)

Comment: can anyone please suggest something

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a compiler bug to me. It is as if the compiler removes the unneeded parentheses from the default `B` value and then it provokes the warning itself.

A workaround:

```
template<size_t V> struct IsPowerOfTwo_Helper
{
    enum { value = V & (V - 1) };
};

template< std::size_t V, bool B = IsPowerOfTwo_Helper<V>::value == 0 > class IsPowerOfTwo_;
```